# Repeating X axis labels and legend labels in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm not sure why I am having such a problem with my x-scale labels repeating as opposed to just labeling where there is a measured point. Additionally, my labels for my legend are not working.

```
 FamIncome Ethnicity    mean.bmi
1   1   1   28.54250
2   1   2   26.66300
3   1   3   26.62105
4   1   4   29.51396
5   1   5   25.66722
6   2   1   29.62404
7   2   2   28.08393
8   2   3   28.62215
9   2   4   28.97561
10  2   5   25.57714
11  3   1   29.52630
12  3   2   28.27235
13  3   3   29.67060
14  3   4   31.36768
15  3   5   26.13361
16  4   1   30.83368
17  4   2   30.80814
18  4   3   29.29594
19  4   4   29.18521
20  4   5   24.80550
21  5   1   29.76500
22  5   2   29.24404
23  5   3   28.89435
24  5   4   31.48172
25  5   5   28.02522
26  6   1   30.05087
27  6   2   29.88574
28  6   3   29.53793
29  6   4   30.97993
30  6   5   25.57857
31  7   1   30.31787
32  7   2   29.28055
33  7   3   28.50421
34  7   4   30.65427
35  7   5   26.66094
36  8   1   29.15000
37  8   2   29.02789
38  8   3   28.36507
39  8   4   33.51915
40  8   5   28.38263
41  9   1   28.17679
42  9   2   28.74731
43  9   3   28.06196
44  9   4   31.38483
45  9   5   26.96000
46  10  1   28.71633
47  10  2   33.44409
48  10  3   30.63048
49  10  4   30.22587
50  10  5   27.36375
51  14  1   30.78161
52  14  2   27.43575
53  14  3   28.96817
54  14  4   32.22378
55  14  5   25.62778
56  15  1   29.15982
57  15  2   27.42672
58  15  3   27.60567
59  15  4   30.05013
60  15  5   26.80271
```

code below:

```
a <- ggplot(nh1, aes(x=FamIncome, y=mean.bmi)) + geom_line(aes(group=Ethnicity, colour = Ethnicity)) + geom_point()
a = a + labs(list(title="Average BMI versus Family Income", x = "Family Income", y = "Average BMI"))
a = a + scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","14","15"),
      labels = c("0-4,999", "5K-9,999", "10K-14,999", "15K-19,999", "20K-24,999", "25K-34,999", "35K-44,999", "45K-54,999", "55K-64,999", "65K-74,999", "75K-100K", "Over 100K"))
a = a + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=-90))
a = a + scale_colour_continuous(name = "Ethnicity", 
                        breaks=c("5","4","3","2","1"),
                        labels=c("Other Race/Multi", "Black","White","Other Hispanic", "Mexican-American"))

a
```

I cannot post a picture of the image that I'm getting until I get 2 more "reputation" points

Comment: @user1317221_G I appreciate you editing the question - I could not figure out how to formate it like that even based off the formatting prompts!

Comment: I can't determine from your description what about the output is wrong. I _can_ tell you that you are using an out of date version of ggplot (`opts` has been deprecated). When I run this I can't spot anything obviously wrong.

Comment: I had wanted to include a picture of what is going wrong but I'm too new to Stack Overflow to do that. What is going on is that I have FamIncome split into 1-10,14 and 15. I'm trying to rename those and when I do that and graph it I am getting breaks in the x-axis in the wrong place and the labeling that I've added begins repeating towards the end. I'm guessing this is an issue with the way the x-axis is breaking and am trying to figure out how to either fix that in ggplot - or how to adjust my dataset
I've added what I have changed to the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting your x variable to a factor:

```
a <- ggplot(nh1, aes(x=factor(FamIncome), y=mean.bmi)) + geom_line(aes(group=Ethnicity, colour = factor(Ethnicity)))
a = a + labs(list(title="Average BMI versus Family Income", x = "Family Income", y = "Average BMI"))
a = a + scale_x_discrete("Family Income", labels = c("0-4,999", "5K-9,999", "10K-14,999", "15K-19,999", "20K-24,999", "25K-34,999", "35K-44,999", "45K-54,999", "55K-64,999", "65K-74,999", "75K-100K", "Over 100K"))
a = a + opts(axis.text.x=theme_text(angle=-90))
a = a + scale_colour_discrete(name = "Ethnicity", 
                        breaks=c("5","4","3","2","1"),
                        labels=c("Other Race/Multi", "Black","White","Other Hispanic", "Mexican-American"))
```

[image]

With a numeric x variable, ggplot is treating it as a numeric scale, when you really intended it to be categorical. Also note the confusing between `fill` and `colour`. `fill` is for two dimensional filled regions.

Comment: That's what I was looking for! I figured it was an issue with that as I was getting errors regarding it being continuous.  
Is there a reason as to why the labeling for the Legend is not working?

Comment: @MryElln Sorry, should have caught that as well. Basically the same fix. Editing...

Comment: @MryElln No problem. Do consider updating your version of ggplot. You are at least 2-3 revisions behind.